# How to create an XML file from an Oracle database in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to output my data from OracleDB to an XML file in Node.js when I run a localhost.

This is part of my code:

```
router.get("/", async function(req, res, next) {
try {
connect = await oracledb.getConnection(information)
const value = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM db')
res.json(js2xmlparser.parse("database", result.rows);
    } catch (err)

}
```

However, when I go to localhost - it prints out the xml text but it is not an xml file.
output in localhost:

```
"<?xml version=1.0'?>\n<database>\n ........ "
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem can be fixed by doing this before you send the output:

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/xml"});
```

But that would depend what `res` is.  I'm just guessing it is an HTTP response.

Regarding the XML itself, you may want to look at the XML capabilities of the database.  You can do fun things like:

```
sql = `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('
          select *
          from employees
          order by employee_id') xml
       from dual`;
binds = [];
options = { fetchInfo: { XML: { type: oracledb.STRING }} };

result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
console.log(result.rows[0][0]);
```

This gives output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>100</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Steven</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>King</LAST_NAME>
  <EMAIL>SKING</EMAIL>
  <PHONE_NUMBER>515.123.4567</PHONE_NUMBER>
  <HIRE_DATE>17-JUN-03</HIRE_DATE>
  <JOB_ID>AD_PRES</JOB_ID>
  <SALARY>24000</SALARY>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>90</DEPARTMENT_ID>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>101</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  . . .
```

Benchmark etc and see which method you prefer

Comment: It works in the terminal for console.log but is there a way for it to work in the browser when I run a local host server? Because this way it is still showing up with the output I showed above.

Comment: Works for me.  I still don't know what `res` is.  Or what browser & XML extension you are using.  Look at the hack code in https://gist.github.com/cjbj/a5f6c7dd6377893cdcca1657406a4b45  In Chrome this shows a tree - which may be what you want.